# Xpath: Get the first node with a certain tag from every subset

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing

For this example I would like to get the first `b` element from every `t` (real xml might be more deeply nested). Unfortunately I am limited to `xpath 1.0`. My initial thought was something like `//t//b[position()=1]` but i can't get it to work.

```
<t>
 <a>
   <b/>
   <b/>
   <b/>
 </a>
</t>
<t>
 <a>
   <b/>
   <b/>
   <b/>
 </a>
</t>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's almost right. First note that the predicate `[position()=1]` is equivalent to simply `[1]`, I'll use the shorter form from now on. Now *by definition*

```
//t//b[1]
```

is shorthand for

```
//t/descendant-or-self::node()/child::b[1]
```

so it will give you all `b` elements that are nested somewhere inside a `t` and are the first `b` child of their respective parent elements. Thus given

```
<t>
  <a>
    <b attr="1"/>
    <b attr="2"/>
  </a>
  <a>
    <b attr="3"/>
  </a>
</t>
```

you would get b's 1 *and* 3. If you only want the first `b` inside each `t` then you need

```
//t/descendant::b[1]
```

Given the example XML above this would return only the `<b attr="1"/>`

You can usually treat `.//x` as equivalent to `descendant::x` but this is one of the edge cases that shows up the subtle distinction between the two...

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation, I was searching the docs, but couldn't find anything that clear :)

Comment: @root the various shorthands like `//` and `@` are very convenient, but it's worth keeping the equivalent long forms in the back of your mind so you can decode the edge cases like this.